# Scale div like an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scale

I am trying to scale content within a div based on it's width.

As an example, I have a div:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

I have styling such as:

```
#container { margin: 0px auto; width: 810px; height: 800px; border: 1px solid #000; }
```

This presents me with a div 810px wide and 800px tall, nicely centered on screen with an outline.

Let's say I have a banner graphic at the top which should scale with the div, so I have it's width at 100%. Works great.

I have a background graphic for the container div itself set to scale with the width as well, working great.

What I need help with, is let's say I had a heading underneath the banner, but this font size needed to scale with everything else, based on the width of the container. How would I accomplish this?

I am also looking to add other elements such as buttons, which would need to scale.

At the end of the day, imagine and image with a width of 100%, and how it scales proportionately, perfectly. This is how I need the container div and all its children to act, like an image. I hope this makes sense.

I have looked at scaling text like in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Aye4h/

This is the perfect behavior, but I need more than just text to scale.

Comment: It looks like your fiddle already scales text. It is hard to determine what your question is, although at least you seem to have included a good amount of information so far. What is "more than just text"? How would you answer this question if you saw someone else ask it?

Comment: Hard to help with only a simple case provided when what you want is a more complex case

Comment: modify the fiddle to include all the other examples, including the failing markup

Comment: It's not my fiddle, somebody elses. I am trying to replicate the same behavior as the text, but for every kind of element. So if there was a button in the mix, the button should scale, just like the text does. Does that make sense? So any element, regardless of what it is, should scale like that text.

Comment: Could you post a sample of what you have so far? It makes things a lot easier for others when we have something to work with, and it shows that you've made an attempt to solve the problem already as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling is a complicated matter as some content is vector based or otherwise rendered on-demand, and some content is raster based (e.g., images). If you want to scale an entire element as if it was just an image, then have a look at `transform: scale`:

```css
#scaled {
  border: #f00 solid 5px;
  background: #0ff;
  height: 500px;
  margin: -125px;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is outside the scaled element</h1>
<div id="scaled">
  <h2>Inside the scaled element</h2>
  <p>An image:</p>
  <p><img src="http://i.imgur.com/3A1Loxw.jpg"></p>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the `transform` is applied after the image has been laid out on the page so all content around it will think it's still at its original size. You can work around this in many other ways, such as by using negative `margin` values (as I did in the example).

Comment: Thank you! You set me on a path using this:

`transform: scale(0.5)`

I was able to get exactly what I wanted after playing with this.

Thank you!